# Delete tuple from a list

Tags: python, list, tuples

I made a program which prints the following output:

```
([1,5],[5,5],[5,1])
```

For the purpose of the program `[1,5]` and `[5,1]` means the same, so I want to delete one of these tuples so the final output would be:

`([1,5], [5,5])` or `([5,5], [5,1])`

How can I do that?

The code is:

```
#Goldbach Conjeture. Finds two prime numbers p,q so n can be written as n = p +q 

from numpy import *
import operator

def prime_list(n):
    prime=[]; srt=[]; mod=[]             # Listas para guardar los numeros      
    primos, las raices de n y los modulos
    i=n
    sq=int(round(sqrt(i)))              
    while(sq>1):                        
        srt.append(sq)                   
        sq=sq-1     
    for j in srt:                        
        m=i%j
        mod.append(m)
    real=0 in mod                        
    if(real==False):                     
    prime.append(i)
    return i
    if(real==True):                      # De lo contrario no es primo
        pass
    return 0

ult=6
prime2=[]; suma=[]
for a in range(1,ult):                  
    b=prime_list(a)
    prime2.append(b)                   
prime2=[x for x in prime2 if x!=0]      

for c in prime2:
    for d in prime2:
        if(c+d==ult):                  
            suma.extend([(c,d)])     
   
print("Los valores p, q tal que sumados sean", ult, "son:", suma)
```

Comment: show us your code

Comment: That's a tuple of lists not a list of tuples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if the order doesn't matter, sort the pairs and convert to and from a set.

```
list(set((tuple(sorted(x, revese=True)) for x in my_list)))
```

A bit of explaining:

1. `sorted` makes sure (5,1) and (1,5) are treated the same. I've added `reverse=True` because this seems to be what you want.
2. wrapping in a tuple makes sure they are treated identically in the set.
3. the set deduplicates them.
4. and you convert back to a list.

Or to write in a less shorthand manner:

```
def deduplicate_pairs(my_list):

    s = set()
    for pair in my_list:
       srt = sorted(pair, reverse=True)
       s.add(tuple(srt)

    return list(s)
```

Comment: @TonyTannous you can reverse the sorting order. see https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted

Answer (score 0):

We can't do a set of collections.Counter, but we can do this:

`deduplicate_pairs = lambda x: set(map(lambda y: tuple(sorted(y)), x))`